# What to use for Workflows after retirement?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, power-automate

> SharePoint 2013 workflow will be turned off for new tenants as of April 2, 2024. It will be removed from existing tenants and will be fully retired as of April 2, 2026

So we are a big company with more than 5000 users and multiple SharePoint 2019 farms. Our SharePoint runs inside Intranet with no internet connection. There is more than 10TB documents running with complex workflows.

After SharePoint 2013 retirement, what can we use? Power Automate requires internet connection (with data gateway) even if you want to run in on-premise.

What is Microsoft's solution for users who has no internet on their environment?

Comment: Check if these links helps: [SharePoint 2013 workflow retirement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-2013-workflow-retirement-4613d9cf-69aa-40f7-b6bf-6e7831c9691e) and [Announcing the release of SharePoint Workflow Manager for SharePoint Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/announcing-the-release-of-sharepoint-workflow-manager-for/ba-p/3744881). Let me know if above links answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @GaneshSanap-MVP, like you provided SharePoint Workflow is going to retired at April 2, 2024. Three months later. It includes SharePoint Workflow Manager because it's 2023 workflow manager.